# How to use regular expressions in awk script?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Hi I'm trying to make a script that will give me a summary of newsgroup activities. Most of it works so far except for when I am trying to use the matching operator to see if this $6 field matches the expression. I want to have all the rings under one section. This is what my script looks like:

newsread.awk:

```
BEGIN{
print "\t\t\tNews Reader Summary\n\n"
printf("               %-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n\n","lonestar","runner","ringer","rings"); 
articles[4];
groups[4];
times[4];
cs2413[4];cs2413d[4];
}

NR == 1 {date1 = $1 " " $2 " " $3}

$6 == "lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu"{
    if ($7=="group"){
        articles[1]+=$9;
        if ($8=="utsa.cs.2413"){
            cs2413[1]+=$9;
        }
        if ($8=="utsa.cs.2413.d"){
            cs2413d[1]+=$9;
        }
    }else if ($7 == "exit"){
        articles[1]+=$9;
        groups[1]+=$11;
    }else {
        times[1]+=$13;
    }
}

$6 == "runner.jpl.utsa.edu"{
    if ($7=="group"){
                articles[2]+=$9;
         if ($8=="utsa.cs.2413"){
                        cs2413[2]+=$9;
                }
                if ($8=="utsa.cs.2413.d"){ 
                        cs2413d[2]+=$9;
                }

        }else if ($7 == "exit"){
                articles[2]+=$9;
                groups[2]+=$11;
        }else {
                times[2]+=$13;
        }

}

$6 == "ringer.cs.utsa.edu"{
    if ($7=="group"){
                articles[3]+=$9;
         if ($8=="utsa.cs.2413"){
                        cs2413[3]+=$9;
                }
                if ($8=="utsa.cs.2413.d"){ 
                        cs2413d[3]+=$9;
                }

        }else if ($7 == "exit"){
                articles[3]+=$9;
                groups[3]+=$11;
        }else {
                times[3]+=$13;
        }

}

$6 ~ "/ring??.cs.utsa.edu/"{
    if ($7=="group"){
                articles[4]+=$9;
         if ($8=="utsa.cs.2413"){
                        cs2413[4]+=$9;
                }
                if ($8=="utsa.cs.2413.d"){ 
                        cs2413d[4]+=$9;
                }

        }else if ($7 == "exit"){
                articles[4]+=$9;
                groups[4]+=$11;
        }else {
                times[4]+=$13;
        }

}
END{
    date2 = $1 " " $2 " " $3
    printf("Articles:      %-15d%-15d%-15d%-15d\n",articles[1],articles[2],articles[3],articles[4]); 
    printf("Groups:        %-15d%-15d%-15d%-15d\n",groups[1],groups[2],groups[3],groups[4]); 
    printf("Cs2413:        %-15d%-15d%-15d%-15d\n",cs2413[1],cs2413[2],cs2413[3],cs2413[4]); 
    printf("Cs2413.d:      %-15d%-15d%-15d%-15d\n",cs2413d[1],cs2413d[2],cs2413d[3],cs2413d[4]); 
    printf("User Time:     %-15d%-15d%-15d%-15d\n",times[1],times[2],times[3],times[4]);  
    printf("\nStart Time = %s\tEnd Time = %s\n",date1,date2); 

}
```

This is a snippet of what news.notice looks like:

```
Feb 13 21:27:14 ringer nnrpd[11474]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu group alt.education.distance 19
Feb 13 21:27:14 ringer nnrpd[11474]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu exit articles 19 groups 1
Feb 13 21:27:14 ringer nnrpd[11474]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu times user 0.470 system 0.930 elapsed 4.766
Feb 13 21:27:49 ringer nnrpd[11462]: ring42.cs.utsa.edu exit articles 0 groups 2
Feb 13 21:27:49 ringer nnrpd[11462]: ring42.cs.utsa.edu times user 2.020 system 1.430 elapsed 45.114
Feb 13 21:28:00 ringer nnrpd[11482]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu group utsa.lonestar 7
Feb 13 21:28:00 ringer nnrpd[11482]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu exit articles 7 groups 1
Feb 13 21:28:00 ringer nnrpd[11482]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu times user 0.520 system 0.890 elapsed 48.286
Feb 13 21:28:38 ringer innd: ME running
Feb 13 21:28:43 ringer nnrpd[11344]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu unrecognized NOOP
Feb 13 21:29:01 ringer nnrpd[11601]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu connect
Feb 13 21:29:01 ringer nnrpd[11601]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu exit articles 0 groups 0
Feb 13 21:29:01 ringer nnrpd[11601]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu times user 0.470 system 0.770 elapsed 1.456
Feb 13 21:29:03 ringer nnrpd[11602]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu connect
Feb 13 21:29:03 ringer nnrpd[11472]: ring29.cs.utsa.edu exit articles 0 groups 0
Feb 13 21:29:03 ringer nnrpd[11472]: ring29.cs.utsa.edu times user 1.360 system 0.790 elapsed 114.771
Feb 13 21:29:03 ringer nnrpd[11602]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu exit articles 0 groups 0
Feb 13 21:29:03 ringer nnrpd[11602]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu times user 0.530 system 0.650 elapsed 1.524
Feb 13 21:29:25 ringer nnrpd[11615]: lonestar.jpl.utsa.edu connect
```

And I am using this command:

```
awk -f newsread.awk news.notice > newsread.summary
```

And here is newsread.summary:

```
            News Reader Summary


               lonestar       runner         ringer         rings          

Articles:      144686         25066          2              0              
Groups:        5282           8344           19             0              
Cs2413:        0              0              0              0              
Cs2413.d:      40             25             0              0              
User Time:     266197         83377          128            0              

Start Time = Feb 13 21:27:14    End Time = Feb 14 20:56:49
```

And it has to be an awk script.

Comment: The "statements" `articles[4];groups[4];times[4];cs2413[4];cs2413d[4];` are unnecessary and probably don't do what you think they do. In all varieties of awk, it is unnecessary to declare arrays, and there is no mechanism for doing so. Arrays spring into existence automatically when they are indexed (or, in some awk implementations, when the script is parsed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get rid of the quotes, i.e. not this:

```
$6 ~ "/ring??.cs.utsa.edu/"
```

but this:

```
$6 ~ /ring??.cs.utsa.edu/
```

Quotes delimit strings, slashes delimit constant REs.

Now, I suspect your RE is wrong since `??` is undefined behavior per POSIX since it's back-to-back repetition metachars and `.` means "any single character". This is a regular expression, not shell globbing - different metacharacters with different meanings.

You probably want this instead:

```
$6 ~ /^ring..\.cs\.utsa\.edu$/
```

Comment: That did it! And your correct, the regex you provided works the way I wanted it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Lose the double quotes.

```
$6 ~ /regex/
```

not

```
$6 ~ "/regex/"
```